# Creating a library that contains instance members

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

In regards to my a little to late discovery that static libraries (obviously) can't have instance members, [How to reference property of static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708155/how-to-reference-property-on-library/708263#708263), is there a way to create a shared library that contains both instance and static members?

On way that probably works is to create a class file, save it to some shared directory and reference it from multiple projects.  Is there a better way?

Comment: I really don't understand the question, static libraries can have instance variables.  "Static" only refers to the fact the libraries are compiled into the main application, and not accessed outside the app at run time.  The link you provided made it look more as if your library was not loaded.

Comment: If the library had not been loaded, then the fileObj instance should not have been created...right?

Comment: I got this working now. Can't exactly say what the fix is.  I read this http://tinyurl.com/cbdwsy and added the -ObjC flag to the static library and host app. Then lots of clean target/rebuid. That's when things started working. I've removed the flag from both locations and still good.

Comment: I don't think the fileObj instance ever was created before, I think it was something else which is why it responded to alloc/init but not the other methods...  I'm glad you got it working though.

Answer (score 1):

I just read an excellent blog post this morning with a nice writeup about sharing code:

http://www.mobileorchard.com/code-sharing-via-static-libraries-and-cross-project-references